# Fixed size for certain objects

Tags: three.js

I have a 3D scene, which includes interface objects rendered over the same perspective camera. I want those objects to have a fixed size based on their distance from their center to the camera.

My current solution involves adding/removing those objects to an array and calculating the bounding sphere for each of those objects every frame and rescaling based on the camera distance to the center of the spheres.

But that doesn't feel right and will at some point cost too many resources once the count of those objects gets big enough. Is there any efficient way to solve this e.g. setting a fixed size for the objects? I don't really want to use a second camera, because that would display the interface objects in a weird way, as if they don't really belong there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want an object to stay the same size as you move the camera closer/further. One method is to first "attach" the item to the camera, then offset it. This would be executed every frame.

```
 fixedSizeObject.position.copy( this.camera.position );
 fixedSizeObject.rotation.copy( this.camera.rotation );
 fixedSizeObject.updateMatrix();
 fixedSizeObject.translateZ( -30 ); //where -30 is the distance you'd like from the camera
```